# Accessing logger when configuring app configurations in .NET Core generic host

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 3.1 application and I'm setting up the [generic host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1) as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging((context, loggingBuilder) =>
        {
            loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
            loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configurationBuilder) =>
        {
            // I want to get an ILogger instance here, but how?
            configurationBuilder.Add(new CustomConfigurationSource(logger));
        })
        // some other setup logic
        .Build().Run();
}
```

The problem is that I want to use an `ILogger` when configuring app configurations. The configuration source I used needs to access a remote server, and also contains some complicated logic for configuration reload, so I want it to be able to write logs for diagnostic and monitoring purposes.

Is there any proper way that this can be done in .NET Core generic host? I would think that this is a pretty legit requirement but can't seem to figure out a way.

The same problem statement also applies to ASP.NET Core applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, we couldn't access the Ilogger since the service hasn't been registered in `CreateDefaultBuilder` method.

If you want to use logger in the ConfigureAppConfiguration, I suggest you could try to create the logger by yourself.

Like below:

```
       Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
 .ConfigureLogging((context, loggingBuilder) =>
 {
    
 })
 .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configurationBuilder) =>
 {
     using (var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole()))
     {
 
      var logger =   loggerFactory.CreateLogger(typeof(Program));
     logger.LogInformation("Example log message");
      }
     // I want to get an ILogger instance here, but how?


 })
 // some other setup logic
 .Build().Run();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the best workaround after I read through [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9337). Feels like quite a limiting issue in generic host though